# What does "fold" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please clarify the meaning of "Fold" in the paragraph below.

> An industrial park in Appalachia may seem an odd place to grow a few
>   million natives of the Nile. But industrial-scale fish farms are
>   popping up everywhere these days. Aquaculture has expanded about
>   **14-fold** since 1980. In 2012 its global output, from silvery salmon to
>   homely sea cucumbers only a Chinese cook could love, reached more than
>   70 million tons—exceeding beef production clearly for the first time
>   and amounting to nearly half of all fish and shellfish consumed on
>   Earth. Population growth, income growth, and seafood’s heart-healthy
>   reputation are expected to drive up demand by 35 percent or more in
>   just the next 20 years. With the global catch of wild fish stagnant,
>   experts say virtually all of that new seafood will have to be farmed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the suffix form of "-fold". Saying "expanded about 14-fold since 1980" is the same as saying "expanded to a size 14 times bigger than it was in 1980". It's basically calling for a multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and straightforward answer. I checked five different dictionaries but failed to find(or understand) it.

Comment: [http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-fold](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-fold). Google *fold suffix*.

Comment: @user3169 Thanks :) I was wrongly searching for "fold" before. I didn't know about suffix.

Comment: It's probably worth flagging up that the most common usage of the suffix is *manifold* (many times), and that in the vast majority of other usages, the number is written out in full (*threefold, tenfold*, etc.). The hyphen isn't usually included unless there are *digits* involved (where it's pretty much unavoidable in the interests of clarity).